# Best way to manage controllers in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Have a project with many controllers.  Putting them all into controllers.js seems ill-advised.  Is there a way in AngularJS to do something like:

```
controllers.js

import/include baseControllers.js
import/include clientControllers.js
import/include searchControllers.js
```

That is, just a way to manage the set of controllers in a single file!

Thanks for any help or pointers.

Comment: I am not sure what you wish to achieve. You could separate your application into modules. Each module would have a 'controllers' directory, which would have different files: one controller per file, easier to read/find. When you deploy, the whole javascript should be minified and included in just one file, except for third-party libraries.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. In my project, there are so many controllers inside a single controller.js file. If i create multiple controllers with individual .js file then i need to add them into index.html, which will be again messy. Is there any other approach to achieve the same ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Putting them all into controllers.js seems ill-advised

Indeed, that would be a mess, assuming you are not writing a *Hello World* application.

Each controller feature should be in a dedicated file that is named after that controller. Each file of the application should be in charge of a **single responsibility**
Then as @Manube said in his comment, at deployment time your application scripts should be minified and concatenated in a single file. Same goes for all the *third-party libraries*. Note also that writing minification-safe code such as :

```
['$scope', function($scope) {
    // ... 
}]
```

is not the responsibility of the developer. It should be handled by plugins like `ng-annotate`.

When you split your components into multiple files, it is important to have a good folder structure. At first glance, a convenient folder structure for your application is to keep your files *by type*. You would then have one folders for all your controllers, one for the directives, one for factories or services, etc. :

## By type

```
app/
    app.config.js
    app.module.js
    app.routes.js
    controllers/
        attendees.js
        session-detail.js
        sessions.js
        shell.js
        speakers.js
        speaker-detail.js
        topnav.js
    directives/
        calendar.directive.js
        calendar.directive.html  
    services/
        dataservice.js
        localstorage.js
        logger.js
        spinner.js
    views/
        attendees.html
        session-detail.html
        sessions.html
        shell.html
        speakers.html
        speaker-detail.html
        topnav.html
```

Please note that the `directives/` folder contains not only the directive's logic, but also their associated templates.
**However**, what if your application grows, and you start to have a lot of controllers, views, services or directives. Well, a structuring by type would not scale very well. So here follows another structure that scales better with large projects. This is a structure *by feature*.

## By feature

```
app/
    app.config.js
    app.module.js
    app.routes.js
    components/
        calendar.directive.js
        calendar.directive.html
        user-profile.directive.js
        user-profile.directive.html
    layout/
        shell.html
        shell.controller.js
        topnav.html
        topnav.controller.js
    people/
        attendees.html
        attendees.controller.js
        people.routes.js
        speakers.html
        speakers.controller.js
        speaker-detail.html
        speaker-detail.controller.js
    services/
        data.service.js
        localstorage.service.js
        logger.service.js
        spinner.service.js
    sessions/
        sessions.html
        sessions.controller.js
        sessions.routes.js
        session-detail.html
        session-detail.controller.js
```

You could also separate your files by features, then by type.

Note: these sample file names come from [AngularJS guidelines by John Papa](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide) which I encourage you to read as they contains other advices aimed *"to provide consistency through good practices"*.

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help you check this one... [Best Practice Recommendations for Angular App Structure](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XXMvReO8-Awi1EZXAXS4PzDzdNvV6pGcuaF4Q9821Es/pub)